# Anchor Expand Area through <li>

Tags: css, jquery-ui

I created a tabs using `jquery-ui` however when I click on the `li` it doesn't change tab... the only way to change it, is to click the `a` anchor itself...

here's my code:
http://jsfiddle.net/4332vo8f/

Comment: I think it has something to do with my css.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by transferring the padding from your `li` elements to `a` elements.

Let's remove the padding in `#tabs ul`, `#tabs ul li`, and when on active state `#tabs li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active` and add padding to `#tabs ul li a` and `#tabs li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active a`

Also let's make sure we add `display: inline-block` to `#tabs ul li` and `#tabs ul li a` so it would expand when we add `padding` to `a`.

Your css should look like this now:

```
#tabs{
    border:1px solid #eedcb8;
    width: 850px;
}
#tabs .ui-tabs-panel{
    padding:0px 10px 10px 10px;
}
#tabs ul{
    background-color: #eedab9;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 5px;
}
#tabs ul li{
    display:inline-block;
    list-style-type:none;
}

#tabs ul li a{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: verdana;
    color:#da8b26;
    text-decoration:none;   
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 5px 35px 5px 10px;    
}

#tabs ul li.ui-state-active a{
    color:white;
    font-family: verdana;
    text-decoration:none;   
    font-size: 14px;

}

#tabs li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active {
    background-color:#d39025;
    margin-right:10px;
    position:relative;    
    color:white;
}

#tabs li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active a {
   padding: 10px 35px 10px 10px;
}

#tabs li.ui-state-default.ui-corner-top.ui-tabs-active.ui-state-active:after{
   border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 30px 38px 0;
    border-color: transparent #eedab9 transparent transparent;
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrotth9n/4/)

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' Cool! Glad to help!